# Extending empty list leaves first element empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to process a few files and append the resulted reads from them to a list in python. To combine all file readings into one list I use the extend method like so:

```
def read_files(filenames)
        reads = list()
    for filename in filenames:
        file_reads = getReads(filename)
        reads.extend(file_reads)

    reads = sorted(reads, key= lambda read: read.datetime)
    return reads
```

Because I initialize the list as empty, after adding all the reads from the files, the first element remains empty and so I get an error when trying to sort the reads on their datetime fields. How can I extend or create a list on the go? I thought of making a check inside the loop and if the list is empty then initialize it with the reads, otherwise simple extend it. Could there be a way where I don't have to do a check inside the for loop? I think that would look cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getReads(filename)` includes a empty element. You do not show your method implementation - you can either debug it and fix it so no empty elements will be returned or remove them before extending (sloppy):

```
file_reads = getReads(filename)
reads.extend( (i for i in file_reads if i) )
```